# Backbone.js: pass model to sub-view by reference

Tags: reference, model, backbone.js, subview

UPDATE: As it turns out, i had a leftover this.model = new MasterModel(); in my subViews initialize() function.

I am trying to separate my huge view to smaller views and so I have created a "master" layout view that attaches to itself some subviews and passes it's model to them.

However, it seems that when my sub-view updates the model, these changes are not reflected on the "master" view's model.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var master = new MasterModel();
var masterView = new MasterView({model:master});
```

Inside of the masterView initialize() function I do this:

```
function: initialize() {
    this.subView = new subView({model:this.model});
}
```

And the code that changes the model in subView is this:

```
function: setCurrency() {
    this.model.set({ currency: this.$('.currency').val() });
}
```

Maybe I am doing something completely wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code so far.  Are you sure that the model is not getting updated?  Or might it be an issue with the updates not getting reflected in the view?

Comment: Models have events that you can bind to like on "change", to update the view. Can I have a look at the event binding of model and what it does when it updates?

Comment: @JayC: Yes, I'm positive. I have a button in the master view that has an alert(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON())) attached to it's click event. When I click the button, the JSON hash does not contain the changes I have made in the sub-views.

Comment: Please show the code that is actually intended to modify the model.

Comment: @JayC: I have updated the question as per your request

Comment: Are you setting a listener in the `subView` for the model change event?  If not, then your subView's `render` method is never getting called again so it's never updating.

Answer (score 0):

How many things have class "currency" are on your page?

<strike>I don't think `this.$('.currency').val()` means what you think it means. I think you're wanting something like `$(this.el).find('.currency').val()`  (are you using 0.9.1?  then you could shorten that to `$el.find('.currency').val()` ).  What you have will always grab the first item on the page with class "currency".  `this.$` is just a convenience reference to what would normally be the global Zepto or jQuery object.  Hence, my question.</strike>

Edit: awaiting response to clarification question.

Comment: I know that. That's not the problem. When I check the model values in SubView after I set them in the subView, they have changed, as I expect. However, when I check the model values in masterView, they are not changed.

Comment: Ok, ok, so... are we dealing with two models here, or one?  Because this is impossible with one model, which is confusing to me.  Per your explanation in the question above, it should be one model instance that every view is getting a reference to, but what you're describing here certainly isn't acting like a single model instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, as it turns out I had a this.model = new.MasterModel(); in my subView initialize() function. Sooooo stupid...

Answer (score -1):

Make your model global so instead of:

```
var master = new MasterModel();
```

use

```
window.master = new MasterModel();
```

and then pas this to your subViews

```
function: initialize() {
    this.subView = new subView({model:window.master});
}
```